# Run class from unpacked .war?

Tags: java, bash, tomcat

Tomcat works with `unpackWAR=true`:

```
    <Host
      name="localhost"
      appBase="webapps"
      unpackWARs="false"
      autoDeploy="false"
      deployOnStartup="true" >
```

Context configured with:

```
$ cat .$CATALINA_HOME/conf/app/localhost/ROOT.xml
<Context docBase="${app.app}/app-web-${app.version}.war" reloadable="true" />
```

But we need to call some classes, which included inside this war.

Previously, when we make war-unpack, we call it with:

```
encryptpwd () {
$JRE_HOME/bin/java -classpath "$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/*" com.***.Encryptor "$1"
}
```

function in `bash` script.

How I can run this class from inside war-file?

Comment: put the war file in classpath and try running. It shouldn't matter whether the war file is exploded or not. As long as Java can find the class in CLASSPATH, it can run it.

Comment: What are you trying to archive?